# How does the .append() function work in python

Tags: python, reference

I made this line of code:

```
alist = [8,6,9,2,4]

blist = [4,5,6]

alist.append(blist)

blist = [7,8,9]

print(alist)
```

I though that this would print **[8, 6, 9, 2, 4, [7, 8, 9]]** but it prints
**[8, 6, 9, 2, 4, [4, 5, 6]]**. Does the .append() function not pass a reference but add a deep copy instead?

Comment: @MorganThrapp `append` does not do a copy.

Comment: @MorganThrapp the *opposite* is true.

Comment: @MorganThrapp It does. Rather than writing `b = [7, 8, 9]`, try `b.append(42)`.

Comment: `blist = [7,8,9]` **does not** modify the original list, it assigns a completely new one to the name `blist`, which doesn't affect `alist` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blist = [7,8,9]` does not mutate the object referred to by `blist`.  Rather, the name `blist` now refers to a new object.  The old object still exists as the last element of `alist`.

```
>>> alist = [8,6,9,2,4]
>>> blist = [4,5,6]
>>> alist.append(blist)
>>> id(blist)
37490560
>>> id(alist[-1]) # should be the same as blist
37490560
>>> blist = [7,8,9] # blist now refers to a new object
>>> id(blist) # its a new object so the id is different
71420104
>>> id(alist[-1]) 
37490560
```

Your mental model seems to be this:  `alist[-1]` refers to `blist` which refers to object `[4,5,6]`.  If that model were correct then `blist = [7,8,9]` would make `alist[-1]` refer to the new value of `blist`.

However, this model is wrong.  `alist.append(blist)` does not make the last element of `alist` refer to `blist`.  It makes the last element refer directly to the object that `blist` refers to at the time it is appended to `alist`.  The name `blist` is not a link in the chain in the relationship between `alist[-1]` and `[4,5,6]`.  That is why assigning to `blist` does not affect the contents of `alist`.

For an extended discussion of this see [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by [Ned Batchelder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14343/ned-batchelder).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

No, you have misunderstood about references and copies. In fact, the opposite of what you say is true; `append` will append a reference to what is currently in `blist`. But it is the *contents* of blist, not the name itself, that are the reference; so if you later change what is assigned to blist, the reference that is also in alist is not affected.

However, if you *mutated* the contents, that would be affected:

```
alist.append(blist)
blist[0] = 7
print(alist)   # => [8, 6, 9, 2, 4, [7, 5, 6]]
```